# Background image not showing up on style.css with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am creating an HTML website using Tailwind CSS and JS. I added an image in styles.css and it is not showing up.

```html
<div class="main-section flex-1">
  <div class="main-section-banner h-44">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.main-section-banner {
  background-image: url("images/amazonbanner.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Set the width of the parent class has no width. If parent has with then mention the source code by using code attribute in the code editor

Comment: Have you tried giving your `main-section-banner` a width as well as a height, e.g. `w-44`?

Comment: Also ensure that the image path is actually correct: check your browser network tab in the dev tools to see if the image is actually loaded.

Answer (score 1):

try to use it like this :

```
<div class="bg-[url('../public/images/hero.jpg')]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your custome style below your tailwind declaration. Like here:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.main-section-banner{
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Tailwind css is initialized via cdn in intex.html file.. is it necessary to add those line of codes in style.css??

Comment: @sanjaydamodharan ok. then it no necessary! Then take care that the custom styles are already loaded. put the link to your custom css above the taildwind cdn link. then would be work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Tailwind `bg-` utility class to add your background image:

```html
<div class="main-section flex-1">
  <div class="bg-[url('https://via.placeholder.com/500')] h-44">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your background css inline like this:

```
<div class="main-section flex-1">
  <div class="h-44 bg-center bg-cover" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/500')">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use arbitary value, make sure you are using Tailwind CSS v3.x with [JIT compiler](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/just-in-time-the-next-generation-of-tailwind-css).